# More efficient way of toggling a divider?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a basic webpage and have created a navbar. Each heading on the navbar toggles one divider to be visible and the rest non-visible. There must be a shorter, simpler, more efficient way to code this?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function Nav1(){
        document.getElementById("Nav1").classList.add("Active");
        document.getElementById("Nav2").classList.remove("Active");
        document.getElementById("Nav3").classList.remove("Active");      
        document.getElementById("Nav4").classList.remove("Active");

        document.getElementById("Div1").classList.remove("d-none");
        document.getElementById("Div2").classList.add("d-none");
        document.getElementById("Div3").classList.add("d-none");
        document.getElementById("Div4").classList.add("d-none");
    }
    ...
```

I am using `d-none` to hide a divider and `Active` is just a class that changes border-colour.

I am very new to javascript so a full explanation would be much appreciated. (I am using Python and Flask for the webpage.)

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure:

- Give to all your "toggleable" dividers a class `.divider`.
- Give each `.divider` a unique id.
- Attach a click handler to each button that toggles a particular divider. 
  The click handler also passes a parameter `id` which is the unique `id`
  of the divider you want to toggle with that button.

Now for CSS:

- Elements with class `divider` should be hidden unless they *also* have a class
  `visible`.

And your JS:

- The `showDivider` function that your click handlers fire selects all elements with class `divider` then iterates (loops) over them.
- If the iterated divider matches the passed id, it adds the class `visible` to it, otherwise it removes it (if it already has it).

Here's a complete example:

```js
function showDivider(id) {
  // Select all elements with class 'divider'.
  document.querySelectorAll('.divider')
    .forEach(divider => {
     // for each element:
     
      // if this divider has the passed id.
      if (divider.getAttribute('id') === id) {
        // add the class 'visible' to it.
        divider.classList.add('visible')
      } else {
        // if not, remove class 'visible' from it.
        divider.classList.remove('visible')
      }
    })
}
```

```css
/* Elements with class "divider" should be hidden. */
.divider {
  display: none;
}

/* Elements with both class "divider" & "visible" should be visible. */
.divider.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showDivider('a');" >Show Divider A</button>
<button onclick="showDivider('b');" >Show Divider B</button>
<button onclick="showDivider('c');" >Show Divider C</button>

<hr>

<div id="a" class="divider">
  Hello Content A!
</div>
<div id="b" class="divider"> 
  Hello Content B!
</div>
<div id="c" class="divider"> 
  Hello Content C!
</div>
```

If you want any element with class `divider` to be visible on page load, just explicitly add the `visible` class to it like so:

```
<div id="a" class="divider visible">
  Hello Content A!
</div>
<div id="b" class="divider"> 
  Hello Content B!
</div>
<div id="c" class="divider"> 
  Hello Content C!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may pass to your function the current element using the this keyword:

```
Nav1(this)
```

Now, you may use the last char of the id and select all Navs and Divs.

```js
function Nav1(ele){
    var eleIdFinalNumnber = this.id.substr(-1); 
    document.querySelectorAll('[id^=Nav]').forEach((ele) =>
         (ele.id.substr(-1) == eleIdFinalNumnber) ? ele.classList.add("Active") :  ele.classList.remove("Active")
    );
    document.querySelectorAll('[id^=Div]').forEach((ele) =>
        (ele.id.substr(-1) == eleIdFinalNumnber) ? ele.classList.remove("d-none") :  ele.classList.add("d-none")
    );
}
```